# Tcsh: Searching history using Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N

Tags: command-history, tcsh, line-editor

What are the equivalent functions in `tcsh` for the following `zsh` functions?

```
up-line-or-history
history-beginning-search-backward
down-line-or-history
history-beginning-search-forward
```

I have the following code in my **,zsh** that I am hoping to translate **in full** to my ".tcsh". The code below is supposed to bind `Ctrl-P` and `Ctrl-N` to such history search functions:

```
up-line-or-history-beginning-search () {
  if [[ -n $PREBUFFER ]]; then
    zle up-line-or-history
  else
    zle history-beginning-search-backward
  fi
}
down-line-or-history-beginning-search () {
  if [[ -n $PREBUFFER ]]; then
    zle down-line-or-history
  else
    zle history-beginning-search-forward
  fi
}


zle -N up-line-or-history-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-history-beginning-search

bindkey '^P' up-line-or-history-beginning-search
bindkey '^N' down-line-or-history-beginning-search
```

Any ideas about what the equivalent `tcsh` code would look like?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about equivalents for everything you posted, but the concept of configuring a keyboard shortcut for the action of searching in the history based on matching the beginning of the current command line is the same in tcsh, so the `bindkey` commands in the example would look like:

```
bindkey '^p' history-search-backward
bindkey '^n' history-search-forward
```

I guess it may depend on the terminal how "Ctrl + P" can be specified to bindkey, I don't know. The caret and letter is what worked for me (which I took from this post, so: thanks! :D).

The description of the actions can be found in the man page of tcsh, under Editing -> Editor commands, or by searching for "history".